# How to avoid using Session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

i have an interface that contains data-grid. When i add element to data-grid, i add it also into List property that is the data-source of my Data-grid. Here the declaration of my list in code-behind:

```
Public Property listeSpecialite() As List(Of RECSPECIALITECONCOURS)
    Get
        Return Session("specialite")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of RECSPECIALITECONCOURS))
        Session("specialite") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and here is the code when i add element to Data Grid :

```
 Protected Sub gridsecialite_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles gridsecialite.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Insert" Then
        Dim dropSpecialite As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtSpecialite_Footer"), DropDownList)

        Dim specialite As New RECSPECIALITECONCOURS
        specialite.CODESPECIALITE = IGS.ChercherParIdInt(Of GENSPECIALITE)(CInt(dropSpecialite.SelectedValue))
        listeSpecialite.Add(specialite)
        gridsecialite.DataSource = listeSpecialite            
        gridsecialite.DataBind()            

    End If
 End Sub
```

and in user **click** save, i save all element in my list to database.

how can i save element of the list without the use of session. (my boss say that it's not good to store list of element in session-performance reason)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to store `listeSpecialite`. Just make sure to understand how it works to ensure that match what you need.

Viewstate has its own drawbacks. More process time for serialization/deserialization, encoding/deocding in B64 and for the page lifecycle in load/restore viewstate of the page, etc. Also, by default, viewstate is sent to the client in a hidden field. This increase bandwidth.

Anyway, if your list has not to be persisted out of your current view I would use `Viewstate`.

EDIT:

With list of 1000 items viewstate will be hurge. How about read from data base persisted items and keep in viewstate just the added items?. You could retrieve items of database, retrieve items from viewstate, combine and bind to datagrid. It is another strategy to avoid session and hurge viewstate at the cost of read database every postback.

As I said, there is no silver bullet...     :-P

Comment: Yes Mr jlvaquero, it's an alternative too, but do you note that there are an impact on performance when we deal with bi List of data (more than 1000 element on list), because i think that the server and the client exchange the element on postback ?

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. In my own post I wrote: "Also, by default, viewstate is sent to the client in a hidden field. This increase bandwidth." You can try gzip http response in server to minimize bandwidth, also you can store viewstate in server side. The point is that there is no silver bullet. Choose a method and deal with drawbacks to minimize them.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Mr  jlvaquero, i think it's a good alternative, i search more for other alternative and then i use the best !